# How to deal with images that are too large in total for the GPU memory using OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

So it is really easy to write a Kernel in OpenCL that takes a few input Image3Ds a few output Image3Ds and do some work with them. It is easy as long as all the input and output images fit into the GPU memory. Now this of course often is not the case, as Image3Ds grow in size rather quickly as you increase the resolution.
So given a Kernel that takes lets say 4 input images and 3 output images, what are the best options to work on them in chunks that fit on the GPU. Is there a form of automatic streaming/buffering?

Best here means: 1) Fast, 2) Little user-written code   (a good mix of the two)

Comment: Try use_host_ptr and calculating 1/10 sized chunks and adding only 1/10 sized temporary device-side-buffers to be used in kernels if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd solve this for 3D images the same way it is solved for 2D image: use tiles. Photoshop did this back when you didn't have enough RAM for large images; it would bring in tiles from disk, process them, and then write the result out. Iterate across image. For 3D, you'd use 3D tiles (little cubes) which fit on the GPU for processing.

Tile engines can be simple or complex, depending on the type of image processing to be done. Also, some algorithms (like recursive Gaussian Blur) need access to all source pixels, so you may need to store intermediate results, load in more tiles, and run more kernels to work your way across a tile set.